# A couple Silverlight 4 questions

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a couple questions regarding Silverlight 4:

1. Does running a Silverlight 4 app, out of browser, in full trust, require the 
   user to respond to a dialog asking for permission? If so, is there a way around this?
2. If the answer to #1 is yes, is the user prompted with the same dialog each time 
   the app is updated?
3. Is full trust only available in an out of browser app, or is it available via the browser as well?
4. If an app is installed out of browser, does the user have to actually do 
   anything to get the app installed? Or is it all transparent?
5. Are there any other installation issues with Silverlight 4 apps that would 
   make installation problematic for a user.

The main reason I ask all this is because we're considering Silverlight 4 for our corporate internal apps and we'd like the deployment process to be seamless and transparent. And since they are internal apps, we don't need our users to confirm it's ok to install in full trust.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much about Silverlight security, but what I know is that if you are developing out-of-browser application (and you can't have full trust in browser anyway), you are severely limited in features. Which means that using .NET Framework is preferable for desktop application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No way around this, the user will be asked whether they trust the application the dialog includes a warning that the application requires elevated trust.
2. No the application can update itself without their seeing this same elevated trust warning again.
3. Currently in SL4 its only available to OOB apps.  SL5 will allow administrators to extend elevated trust to in browser apps via group policy.
4. The inbrowser version needs to give the user a some form of UI (button) to invoke installation (the ability to install is also added to the default context menu for the application).  The user will then need to agree to the dialog presented.  After that the user will need to close their current usage and manually start the newly installed app.
5. Not that I know of, a part from the presence of Silverlight runtime there are no other dependencies.

For you requirements you might be better looking at a different technology right now but SL5 may fit your needs in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to install a Silverlight application as an OOB application with elevated permissions using the command prompt. If you have a system adminstrator controlling what the users get installed on their computers you can install the application without bothering the user.

When the application is installed an update will not prompt the security dialog. But in some scenarios it makes sense to restart the application.

In SL4 elevated trust requires the application to run OOB.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this article](http://johnpapa.net/silverlight/digitally-signing-a-xap-silverlight/) about signing Silverlight applications it might help you with several of these issues. By signing you could overcome trust issues and the users to be bothered with dialogs.

**EDIT** [Read this too](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2010/03/23/silverlight-4-rc-signing-trusted-apps-with-home-made-certificates.aspx) it explains more about trusting the publisher and updating